# ParallelEnumerable.Range vs Enumerable.Range.AsParallel?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, parallel-processing

What is the differences between `ParallelEnumerable.Range`  and  `Enumerable.Range(...).AsParallel()`?

`ParallelEnumerable.Range` creates range partition( best for operations where cpu time is equal foreach item)

where as `Enumerable.Range(...).AsParallel()` might be executes as `range` or `chunk`

Is there any performance difference ? When should I use which ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're performing an operation where it's CPU pressure grows as it iterates then you're going to want to use `AsParallel` because it can make adjustments as it iterates. However, if it's something that you just need to run in parallel and the operation doesn't create more pressure as it iterates, then use `ParallelEnumerable.Range` because it can partition the work immediately.

Reference [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/chunk-partitioning-vs-range-partitioning-in-plinq/) for a more detailed explanation.

So, let's assume you're performing some complex math in each iteration, and as the input values grow the math takes longer, you're going to want to use `AsParallel` so that it can make adjustments. But if you use that same option with something like setting a registry setting, you'll see a performance decrease because there is overhead associated with `AsParallel` that is not necessary.