# Why does ToList() make a sorted order?

Tags: c#, .net-8.0, plinq, tolist

When I execute the following code:

```
using static System.Console;

var numbers = ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, 50);

WriteLine("\nNumbers divisible by 5 are:");
var divisibleBy5 = numbers
    .AsParallel()
    .WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism)
    .Where(x => x % 5 == 0);
   // .Where(x => x % 5 == 0)
   //.ToList();
foreach (var number in divisibleBy5)
{
    Write(number + "\t");
}
```

I can see the unordered result most of the time. Here is a sample output (Expected behavior):

```
Numbers divisible by 5 are:
0       15      30      40      5       20      35      45      10      25
```

Now I change the query a little bit (using `ToList()` now):

```
var divisibleBy5 = numbers
    .AsParallel()
    .WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism)
    //.Where(x => x % 5 == 0);
    .Where(x => x % 5 == 0)
   .ToList();
```

Upon running this update, I **always** see the sorted output:

```
Numbers divisible by 5 are:
0       5       10      15      20      25      30      35      40      45
```

**Questions:**

1. Is this an expected behavior?
2. If so, why? Do we have any supporting docs for this?

What am I missing here? Can you please share your thoughts?

Comment: See [ParallelEnumerable.Range vs Enumerable.Range.AsParallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645354/parallelenumerable-range-vs-enumerable-range-asparallel) and the linked article [Chunk partitioning vs range partitioning in PLINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645354/parallelenumerable-range-vs-enumerable-range-asparallel)

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043039/does-listt-guarantee-insertion-order

Comment: `Range` will create values in numeric sequence, i.e. ordered. `Where` uses deferred execution, i.e. the values are provided as threads complete. `ToList` uses immediate evaluation and creates a complete `List`, i.e. the values will be ordered as produced by `Range`.

Comment: @azpc: In your link, the accepted answer says-"The List<> class does guarantee ordering - things will be retained in the list in the order you add them, including duplicates, unless you explicitly sort the list."- but here the case is opposite. I did not sort prior to the ToList() call

Comment: @NotFound with the "AsEnumerable" you simply changed the ToList overload from the ParallelQuery to the IEnumerable one. Different code different behavior.  It does not explain why the ParallelEnumerable behave differently.

Comment: @Jonathan Dodds: Thanks. Yes,once I made a new list from the initial query as follows: var newList = divisibleBy5.ToList(); traversing this newList produces unordered output. I was  not aware that inside PLINQ queries, calls can be overlapped like this and create this kind of sorted output.

Comment: As a side note, the `ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, 50).AsParallel()` includes a superfluous `AsParallel` operator. The `ParallelEnumerable.Range` already gives you a `ParallelQuery<int>`. You would need the `.AsParallel()` only if you had started with the non-parallel sequence `Enumerable.Range(0, 50)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The explanation for the behavior is as follows:

1. The queries returned by [`ParallelEnumerable.Range()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.range), [`AsParallel()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel) and [`Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.where) are all of base type [`ParallelQuery<int>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelquery-1).
2. Because of that, when you call the extension method `ToList()` you are actually invoking [`ParallelEnumerable.ToList<int>(this ParallelQuery<int>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.tolist) rather than [`Enumerable.ToList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist).
3. `ParallelEnumerable.ToList<int>()` has a special case for ordered parallel enumerables that preserves order.  This is mentioned briefly in the documentation page [Query Operators and Ordering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/order-preservation-in-plinq#query-operators-and-ordering):

   > Some PLINQ query operators behave differently, depending on whether their source sequence is ordered or unordered. The following table lists these operators:
   >
   > | Operator | Result when the source sequence is ordered | Result when the source sequence is unordered |
   > | --- | --- | --- |
   > | [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.range) | Not applicable (same default as [`AsParallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel)) | Not applicable |
   > | [`ToList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.tolist) | ***Ordered results*** | Unordered results |
   > | [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.where) | ***Ordered results*** | Unordered results |

   Thus as long as the preceding parts of your query are ordered, `Where()` and `ToList()` are documented to preserve that order while `GetEnumerable()` is not.

   That being said, `ParallelEnumerable.Range()` is not documented to return an ordered parallel enumerable (the docs seem ambiguous to me), so we can't say for sure that your final list will be ordered.  But we can explain why `ToList()` and `foreach` might produce different orderings.

To see how this works in practice, we can check the .NET 8 [reference source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/v8.0.1) and do some debugging.  The source code for `ToList()` can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.1/src/libraries/System.Linq.Parallel/src/System/Linq/ParallelEnumerable.cs#L4844):

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this ParallelQuery<TSource> source)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);

    // Allocate a growable list (optionally passing the length as the initial size).
    List<TSource> list = new List<TSource>();
    IEnumerator<TSource> input;

    if (source is QueryOperator<TSource> asOperator)
    {
        if (asOperator.OrdinalIndexState == OrdinalIndexState.Indexable && asOperator.OutputOrdered)
        {
            return new List<TSource>(ToArray<TSource>(source));
        }

        // We will enumerate the list w/out pipelining.

        // @PERF: there are likely some cases, e.g. for very large data sets,
        //     where we want to use pipelining for this operation. It can reduce memory
        //     usage since, as we enumerate w/ pipelining off, we're already accumulating
        //     results into a buffer. As a matter of fact, there's probably a way we can
        //     just directly use that buffer below instead of creating a new list.

        input = asOperator.GetEnumerator(ParallelMergeOptions.FullyBuffered);
    }
    else
    {
        input = source.GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Debugging indicates that the concrete type of `source` is [`WhereQueryOperator<int>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.1/src/libraries/System.Linq.Parallel/src/System/Linq/Parallel/QueryOperators/Unary/WhereQueryOperator.cs) with [`OrdinalIndexState`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.1/src/libraries/System.Linq.Parallel/src/System/Linq/Parallel/QueryOperators/OrdinalIndexState.cs) equal to `OrdinalIndexState.Increasing` when means that `GetEnumerator(ParallelMergeOptions.FullyBuffered)` rather than just `GetEnumerator()` is called. The source for these methods is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.1/src/libraries/System.Linq.Parallel/src/System/Linq/Parallel/QueryOperators/QueryOperator.cs#L95):

```
public override IEnumerator<TOutput> GetEnumerator()
{
    // Buffering is unspecified and  order preservation is not suppressed.
    return GetEnumerator(null, false);
}

public IEnumerator<TOutput> GetEnumerator(ParallelMergeOptions? mergeOptions)
{
    // Pass through the value supplied for pipelining, and do not suppress
    // order preservation by default.
    return GetEnumerator(mergeOptions, false);
}

internal virtual IEnumerator<TOutput> GetEnumerator(ParallelMergeOptions? mergeOptions, bool suppressOrderPreservation)
{
    // Return a dummy enumerator that will call back GetOpenedEnumerator() on 'this' QueryOperator
    // the first time the user calls MoveNext(). We do this to prevent executing the query if user
    // never calls MoveNext().
    return new QueryOpeningEnumerator<TOutput>(this, mergeOptions, suppressOrderPreservation);
}
```

I.e. the difference between the enumerator used by `ToList()` and the default enumerator used by `foreach` is the former passes [`ParallelMergeOptions.FullyBuffered`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelmergeoptions?view=net-8.0), which is documented as follows:

> Use a merge with full output buffers. The system will accumulate all of the results before making any of them available to the consumer of the query.

This seems to be the cause of the inconsistency you are seeing.

To confirm that the behavior you are seeing is specific to `ParallelEnumerable.ToList()`, I modified your query to cast to `IEnumerable<int>` before calling `ToList()`:

```
IEnumerable<int> divisibleBy5Query = numbers // IEnumerable<int> is implemented by ParallelQuery<int>
    .WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism)
    .Where(x => x % 5 == 0);
var divisibleBy5 = divisibleBy5Query
    .ToList();
```

When I did so, this resulted in a randomly ordered list.

You can see a demo fiddle showing all my variations of your `divisibleBy5` query here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qBccva.

Comment: Notice that if you switch from `ParallelEnumerable.Range` to `Enumerable.Range`, the results are no longer ordered ([demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sG73cB)). So the accidental ordering is not just an effect of the PLINQ `ToList`. It depends also on hidden attributes of the originating parallel sequence. Honestly all this research looks like an exercise to futility to me. If someone wants ordered results, they just have to include the `AsOrdered` in their query. That's the professional thing to do. Everything else is being fancy with undocumented and unreliable behaviors for no reason.

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias: Thanks for your thoughts. But if you carefully see the question (or discussions), you'll acknowledge that the concern was not about "how" to get an ordered result. Instead, it is "why" are we seeing the ordered/sorted result?

Comment: @VaskaranSarcar and what will you do with this information?

Comment: @dbc: True. I acknowledged this saying something similar  to Jonathan Dodds as well. Notice that you need to segregate the query into 2 parts. Doing this can produce this unordered result. I'd only like to add that in this case, I "do not need to cast " to IEnumerable<int> to see the unordered result. Only segregating the query in 2 parts like this was sufficient for me to see the unordered output.

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias: I thought that I was missing some basic info that you people already know. So, i was curious and  I asked the question.

Comment: @VaskaranSarcar and what did you learn after asking the question and reading the answers? That being curious sometimes yields information that has no practical application?

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias:  I doubt whether "discussing like this" helps the community. However,  I must thank you for sharing your thoughts and helps towards all my questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to receive the results in the original order, the correct thing to do is to use the [`AsOrdered`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asordered) PLINQ operator:

```
ParallelQuery<int> divisibleBy5 = numbers
    .AsParallel()
    .AsOrdered()
    .Where(x => x % 5 == 0);
```

The [`ToList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.tolist) PLINQ operator might produce an ordered result accidentally. This is not documented, and it is certainly not something you should rely on (assuming that your goal is to write a program that behaves correctly consistently).